# Cost of travelling and living coverage in the visa application

Tags: schengen, applications, denmark, conferences

[image]

I am a college student who graduated a month ago. I am applying for a short-term visa to Denmark. My mother, who is supporting me and resides in another country (different from mine and Denmark), has sent me the funds to cover my travel and stay.

Do I tick that the cost is being covered by myself (since I now possess the funds) or should I tick that it is being covered by a sponsor (my mother)?

Comment: How long ago did you receive the money?

Comment: Received it two weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Under the circumstances, it might be wise to use both sections, indicating on one that you have the funds in cash (and any other means) and the other to show that you receive financial support from a family member. As you're a recent graduate and may be unemployed, it would make more sense than having no logical (or visible) means of support or income.